# iPhone - Toolbar in UIViewController disappear right after showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I use this code to display a one item Toolbar in UIViewController (which is pushed by UINavigationController). The toolbar shows up and immediately disappear:

```
UIBarButtonItem * logoutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log out" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:logoutButton, nil];
[self setToolbarItems:arr animated:NO];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: where is this code? Doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary here so either has to do with where you are calling it, or something else that happens afterwards (like setting toolbarHidden to YES later or something)

Comment: I figured out where the problem is. There is a place in my application that set the toolbar to hide for all view controllers on UINavigationController stack.

Comment: @Jess: can you put your comment as an answer because I'd like to make this question |ANSWERED| but can't do it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is this code? Doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary here so either has to do with where you are calling it, or something else that happens afterwards (like setting toolbarHidden to YES later or something)